# Avoiding interpretation as octal in a C macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, octal

In an application I'm working on, we have a macro to convert clock times into an internal representation as a short integer:

```
#define CLOCK_TIME(hr, min) (s32)(((hr) * 60 + (min)) * 0x10000 / (24 * 60))
```

Naturally, we would write the hours and minutes exactly as they'd appear on a clock. So, for example, 6:30 would be `CLOCK_TIME(6, 30)`. This all worked fine until someone tried to enter `CLOCK_TIME(6, 08)` and the compiler spat out an error saying `08` is not a valid octal constant. We tried a few workarounds, but they led to their own problems. For example, replacing `min` with `1##min - 100` fixed that specific issue, but then the macro would fail with any input that wasn't a 2-digit decimal literal. Is there a way we could allow `08` and `09` to work in the macro while also allowing arguments that may be single digits, expressions, or variables?

And yes, I realize just not using leading zeroes is a solution, but having the times appear the way they appear on a clock improves both readability and usability.

EDIT: One additional constraint is that if the time is a constant, it *must* be calculated at compile time and not runtime.

Comment: You could put a `0x` on the front, and then it would not be interpreted as an octal constant, as requested.  Alternatively, you could suffix it with a `.` so that it is a floating-point constant, which you then cast to `int`. A floating-point constant that is an immediate operand of a cast to an integer type counts as an *integer constant expression*. That allows single or multiple digits, including leading zeros, but not expressions or variables.

Comment: All of “single digits, expressions, or variables” — no. The CPP just isn’t that smart.

Comment: Append suffix `e0`.

Comment: @Dúthomhas In that case, what's the best I can do? The other comments suggest ways to do decimal constants of any length. Is my choice between that and having it work with expressions/variables but not `08` and `09`?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe something like append a `"0"` to `min` with `min##0` and then use `#` to make that a string.  Then `(string[0]-'0')*10 + (string[1]-'0')`?  Macro magic involved.

Comment: "We tried a few workarounds" It would appear that the correct work-around is to educate your programmers about how integer constants work in C. Not to invent macros that work differently than the rest of the language as a special case.

Comment: @Lundin Entering a time with a redundant leading zero is a common use case while entering a time in octal will probably never happen. Why not try to make a macro conform to how people will actually use it rather than how no one will?

Comment: @eyeballfrog "Entering a time with a redundant leading zero is a common use case" No it isn't since that is invalid C. It doesn't make sense to create a macro which one moment accepts a plain integer variable that works like any other variable in C, and in the next moment wants octal numbers which it mysteriously re-formats. The target audience is C programmers and you can expect them to know how integer constants work, since accidental octal numbers is a common beginner FAQ. Also why a macro and not a function if you intend to pass run-time variables to it?

Comment: If this is only for compile-time calculations then a macro at least makes sense somewhat. And I might have a (ugly) solution in that case.

Comment: @Lundin At the moment we don't intend to pass runtime variables to it, but I wanted to know if there was a way to handle both in one macro in case that came up later. I figured it was worth asking if a macro could be created that has constants calculate at compile time, works with runtime variables, and has `08` and `09` work as intended. From the answers it appears there is not, so we'll have to decide which is least important.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Just for reference I posted the compile-time evil macro version as an answer now. It's ugly as sin but pure compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

As @dimich suggested, you can append scientific notation `e0`.
This will first force the number to be a double, then you can type-cast it back to an `int`.

```
#define CLOCK_TIME(hr, min) (int32_t)(((hr) * 60 + (int32_t)(min##e0)) * 0x10000 / (24 * 60))
```

This works because `08e0` is valid as `(double)8.000`, even though `08` is invalid octal.

### [IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/gLXK5R)

Comment: For the purposes of this application, it is necessary that whenever the time is a constant, it is calculated at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

A solution for any number of digits (within implementation limits) (but not expressions or variables) is `1##min*2 - 2##min`. This can be thought of as (10<sup>*p*</sup>+*x*)•2 − (2•10<sup>*p*</sup>+*x*), where *p* is the unknown number of digits in *x*, and it equals (2•10<sup>*p*</sup>+2x)−(2•10<sup>*p*</sup>+*x*) = 2*x*−*x* = *x*. This avoids floating-point issues.

For example, `23` would be replaced by `123*2 - 223`, which equals 23. `08` would be `108*2 - 208` = 8, and `8` would be `18*2 - 28` = 8.

A solution that handles numerals, expressions, and variables is to write your own script outside of C. Humans are not required to limit their programs to the C preprocessor. You can write your own script to remove leading zeros from numerals inside invocations of this macro and then use this script to process the source code before compiling it.

Answer (score 0):

> but then the macro would fail with any input that wasn't a 2-digit decimal literal

The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define POW10I(x) ( \
    x == 0 ? 1 : \
    x == 1 ? 1 : \
    x == 2 ? 10 : \
    x == 3 ? 100 : \
    x == 4 ? 1000 : \
    x == 5 ? 10000 : \
    x == 6 ? 100000 : \
    x == 7 ? 1000000 : \
    x == 8 ? 10000000 : \
    x == 9 ? 100000000 : \
    -1 )
#define TOBASE10IN(one_and_x, strx)   (one_and_x - POW10I(sizeof(strx)))
#define TOBASE10(x) TOBASE10IN(1##x, #x)

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", TOBASE10(0123456));
}
```

outputs 123456.

> Is there a way we could allow 08 and 09 to work in the macro while also allowing arguments that may be single digits, expressions, or variables?

No.

If are willing to use runtime, you can then just do anything. Just parse the whole string representation of the expression and check if it is an octal number and take a different branch then.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
bool isdigits(const char str[]) {
    for (; *str; str++) {
        if (!isdigit(*str)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
int tobase10(int x, const char xstr[]) {
    if (xstr[0] == '0' && isdigits(xstr)) {
        return strtol(xstr, NULL, 10);
    }
    return x;
}
#define TOBASE10(x) tobase10(x, #x)

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", TOBASE10(0123456));
    int a = 10;
    printf("%d\n", TOBASE10(a + a));
}
```

My take: I find it confusing that you *want* to change an internal part of C programming language. Octal numbers may be confusing for new users of the language, but I find that such macro usage will be confusing for the rest of the world. I would rather just leave a comment near the macro to watch out and learn about octal numbers.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way we could allow 08 and 09 to work in the macro while also allowing arguments that may be single digits, *expressions, or variables*?

(Emphasis mine)

No, there is absolutely no way whatsoever to achieve that using C preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the values passed to the macro as digits, with `gcc` it is possible to make a conversion from string to integers suppressing the leading 0 thanks to a [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html):

```c
#define CLOCK_TIME(hr, min) ({ \
                   char __hr[3] = #hr, __min[3] = #min; \
                   int __hrv = 0, __minv = 0, __mul, __i; \
                   __mul = 1;__i = sizeof(#hr) - 2; \
                   while (__i >= 0) { __hrv += (__hr[__i --] - '0') * __mul; __mul *= 10; }  \
                   __mul = 1; __i = sizeof(#min) - 2;  \
                   while (__i >= 0) { __minv += (__min[__i --] - '0') * __mul; __mul *= 10; } \
                   (int)(((__hrv) * 60 + (__minv)) * 0x10000 / (24 * 60)); \
                            })
```

This solves the leading 0 problem but the calculation is done at runtime and this works only for digits passed to the macros (no variable or expression).

Answer (score 0):

Defining this as macro rather than a function only makes sense if you intend for this number to be calculated at compile-time. So assuming that the macro will *not* get passed run-time variables but only digits at compile-time...

...then it is possible to conjure some evil magic macro language (not recommended) taking `hh:mm` as input but also allowing `h:mm` (but not `hh:m`). The caller side would look something like this:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  printf("%" PRIi32 "\n", CLOCK_TIME(6:30));  // 17749
  printf("%" PRIi32 "\n", CLOCK_TIME(6:08));  // 16748
  printf("%" PRIi32 "\n", CLOCK_TIME(12:00)); // 32768
}
```

And the evil macro would look something along the lines of:

```
#define CALCULATE_STUFF(hr, min) (int32_t)(((hr) * 60 + (min)) * 0x10000 / (24 * 60))

#define STRLEN(str) (sizeof(str) - 1)
#define STR(arg) #arg

#define CLOCK_TIME(arg)                                              \
  STRLEN(STR(arg)) < 4 ? 0 :                                         \
  STRLEN(STR(arg)) > 5 ? 0 :                                         \
  STRLEN(STR(arg))==4 && STR(arg)[1]!=':' ? 0 :                      \
  STRLEN(STR(arg))==5 && STR(arg)[2]!=':' ? 0 :                      \
  CALCULATE_STUFF(                                                   \
    STRLEN(STR(arg))==4 ? (STR(arg)[0]-'0') :                        \
                          (STR(arg)[0]-'0')*10 + (STR(arg)[1]-'0')   \
  ,                                                                  \
    STRLEN(STR(arg))==4 ? (STR(arg)[2]-'0')*10 + (STR(arg)[3]-'0') : \
                          (STR(arg)[3]-'0')*10 + (STR(arg)[4]-'0')   \
  )
```

Explanation:

- This macro returns 0 if incorrect, but could as well return some other integer to signal that something went wrong.
- The error handling is based on "chaining" multiple `?:` operators which has very low precedence, to the point where you can write pretty much anything as operands. It kind of works like a bunch of static assertions (and you could pass the result of the macro to `_Static_assert` if you fancy).
- The `STR` helper macro converts the input to a string literal like `"hh:mm"` and the whole macro works on strings.
- Therefore we can do a compile-time "strlen" call by taking the size of string literal, minus 1 for the null terminator.
- First the macro checks that there's enough digits by calling a macro `STRLEN` and then that the `:` is in one of the allowed places.
- Once the input format is considered ok, the actual calculation (which I didn't examine for correctness) is carried out in  `CALCULATE_STUFF`.
- `CALCULATE_STUFF` takes two arguments and depending on which input format that was used, it does a character to integer conversion, multiplying the first digit out of two by 10.

This macro comes with zero overhead and the `CLOCK_TIME(6:30)` etc calls are replaced with integers at compile-time.

Comment: There's probably a bunch of corner cases that require extra error handling, so just take this concept for what it's worth.